# Error al crear un nodo en una lista enlazada

Tags: c, lista

Estoy cambiando un ejercicio que crea una lista enlazada de enteros a una lista enlazada con cadenas de texto. Pero tengo un error en el método `push()`, que he adaptado del ejercicio original que si funciona.

Tengo una lista enlazada definida así:

```
typedef struct nombreLista {
  char nombre[50];
  struct nombreLista* siguiente;
} Nombre;
```

Creo las variables que necesito, para la lista y el índice de la lista:

```
Nombre *pNombres;
int size;
```

A continuación inicializo la lista:

```
void init() {
  pNombres = NULL;
  size = 0;
}
```

Ahora, tengo esta función para poner un elemento en la lista, recibe un nombre como parámetro y trata de insertar este dato en la lista, regresando un 0 su tuvo éxito y un -1 en caso de fallo.

```
int push(char dato[50]) {
  Nombre* nodo = (Nombre *)malloc(sizeof(Nombre)); // No sé que hace esta línea
  if (nodo != NULL) {
    nodo->nombre = dato;
    nodo->siguiente = pNombres;
    pNombres = nodo;
    size++;
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("No se pudo agregar el nombre");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Me aparece un error de compilación:

> `error C2106: '=': el operando izquierdo debe ser valor L`

El IDE muestra el error en la línea `nodo->nombre = dato;` con la leyenda **`la expresión debe ser un valor L modificable`**. El compilador es que viene con Visual Studio 2019.

¿Qué significa el error y cómo puedo solucionarlo? Adicional, ¿qué hace la línea `Nombre* nodo = (Nombre *)malloc(sizeof(Nombre));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Qué significa el error y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

El error significa que no puedes asignar ningún elemento al puntero implicito `nombre`.

Es como si hicieras esto:

```c
char nombre[24];
nombre = "Hola";
```

Dará error de compilación, solo es válido asignarle algo (debe ser una cadena literal) a `nombre` al momento de declararlo.

Por ejemplo:

```c
char nombre[24] = {"PaperMaster"}; //es válido
```

Si el identificador `nombre` fuera miembro de una estructura, daría el mismo error:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   char nombre[24];
};
A a;
a.nombre = "Dave"; //error
```

También dará error de compilación porque no podemos asignarle nada al miembro `nombre` después de la declaración de `A`. En cambio, si hago esto:

```c
A a = {3, "Dave"};
```

Ahí no daría error de compilación, debido a que, se está asignando la cadena "Dave" en `nombre` pero en la declaración de `a`, por lo tanto, ahí no habría ningún problema.

**Solución:**

Puedes hacer uso de la función [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) para poder copiar el contenido de un arreglo de tipo `char` en otro.

Código en C:

```c
int push(char dato[50]) {
  Nombre* nodo = (Nombre *)malloc(sizeof(Nombre)); 
  if (nodo != NULL) {
    strcpy(nodo->nombre, dato);
    nodo->siguiente = pNombres;
    pNombres = nodo;
    size++;
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("No se pudo agregar el nombre");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Otra solución para poder ahorrarse la función `strcpy`, es cambiando la declaración de `nombre`.

Es decir, si tenías definida la estructura de esta forma:

```c
typedef struct nombreLista {
  char nombre[50];
  struct nombreLista* siguiente;
} Nombre;
```

La puedes cambiar a:

```c
typedef struct nombreLista {
  const char* nombre;
  struct nombreLista* siguiente;
} Nombre;
```

Ahí no daría ningún error de compilación.

**¿Por qué?** Porque la variable `nombre` ahora si es modificable y esto se debe porque fue declarado como un puntero explicito.

Esto es como si hicieras esto:

```c
char nombre[24] = "Dave";
const char* n = nombre;
```

Lo que recibe `n` es la dirección base del arreglo `nombre` (es decir, del primer elemento).

> > ¿qué hace la línea Nombre* nodo = (Nombre *)malloc(sizeof(Nombre));?

La función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) lo que hace es reservar memoria dinámica en tiempo de ejecución (en este caso, lo que crea en memoria, es un búfer de datos). En la cual, retornará la primera dirección de memoria del nodo y se la guarda en la variable `nodo`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, las dos opciones mostradas funcionaron. Adicionalmente, creo que configuré mal el proyecto, porque el código compila correctamente en CLion en Windows y en Linux, pero no en Visual Studio.